# Changing to a multiple column situation in php

Tags: php, android, css, wordpress

Recently we've been creating a website for our business using a purchased WP theme (Jupiter) that my boss, the owner, has had a few very particular modifications he's wanted (some for reasons I don't understand) and given I have working knowledge of HTML and CSS, and very very basic PHP knowledge, I have attempted and been able to make all his customizations except one:

The theme is designed to be responsive, and as such, the custom portfolio gallery style (which appears like an image gallery on computers: http://14d.mercysou.server312.com/photos) will progressively shrink on different devices so that by the time you are down to a smartphone, only 1 column of images will show up and you can scroll down.  My supervisor would like it to be customized so that regardless of screen size, even on phones, there is at minimum 2 columns of images across the screen at all times.  The PHP for this portfolio gallery (called "masonry") is as follows:

```
<?php
function mk_portfolio_masonry_loop(&$r, $atts)
{
global $post;
extract($atts);
global $mk_options;

$output     = '';
$terms      = get_the_terms(get_the_id(), 'portfolio_category');
$terms_slug = array();
$terms_name = array();
if (is_array($terms)) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $terms_slug[] = $term->slug;
        $terms_name[] = '<span>' . $term->name . '</span>';
    }
}

$post_type = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_single_post_type', true);
$post_type = !empty($post_type) ? $post_type : 'image';
$link_to   = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_portfolio_permalink', true);

$hover_overlay_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_hover_skin', true);
$hover_overlay       = !empty($hover_overlay_value) ? (' style="background-color:' . $hover_overlay_value . '"') : '';

$column = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_masonry_img_size', true);
$column = !(empty($column)) ? $column : 'x_x';

switch ($column) {
    case 'x_x':
        $width  = 300;
        $height = 300;
        break;

    case 'two_x_x': // 
        $width  = 600;
        $height = 300;
        break;

    case 'three_x_x':
        $width  = 900;
        $height = 300;
        break;
    case 'four_x_x':
        $width  = 1200;
        $height = 300;
        break;

    case 'x_two_x':
        $width  = 300;
        $height = 600;
        break;
    case 'two_x_two_x':
        $width  = 600;
        $height = 600;
        break;
    case 'three_x_two_x':
        $width  = 900;
        $height = 600;
        break;

    case 'four_x_two_x':
        $width  = 1200;
        $height = 600;
        break;

    default:
        $width  = 300;
        $height = 300;
        break;
}

$lightbox_full_size = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full', true);

$permalink = '';
if (!empty($link_to)) {
    $link_array = explode('||', $link_to);
    switch ($link_array[0]) {
        case 'page':
            $permalink = get_page_link($link_array[1]);
            break;
        case 'cat':
            $permalink = get_category_link($link_array[1]);
            break;
        case 'portfolio':
            $permalink = get_permalink($link_array[1]);
            break;
        case 'post':
            $permalink = get_permalink($link_array[1]);
            break;
        case 'manually':
            $permalink = $link_array[1];
            break;
    }
}
if ($ajax == 'true' || empty($permalink)) {
    $permalink = get_permalink();
}
$output .= '<article id="' . get_the_ID() . '" class="mk-portfolio-item mk-portfolio-masonry-item masonry-'.$item_id.' mk-isotop-item  ' . $hover_scenarios . '-hover size_' . $column . ' portfolio-' . $post_type . ' ' . implode(' ', $terms_slug) . '">';
$image_src_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full', true);
$image_src       = bfi_thumb($image_src_array[0], array(
    'width' => $width * $image_quality,
    'height' => $height * $image_quality
));

$item_bg_color_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_hover_skin', true);
$item_bg_color       = !empty($item_bg_color_value) ? (' background-color:' . $item_bg_color_value . '!important') : '';
$output .= '<div style="margin:0 ' . ($grid_spacing / 2) . 'px ' . $grid_spacing . 'px;" class="item-holder">';

//$output .= ($hover_scenarios == 'fadebox' || $hover_scenarios == 'none') ? '<a class="project-load" data-post-id="' . get_the_ID() . '" href="' . $permalink . '">' : '';


$output .= '<div class="featured-image">';
$output .= '<img alt="' . get_the_title() . '" class="item-featured-image" title="' . get_the_title() . '" src="' . mk_thumbnail_image_gen($image_src, $width, $height)  . '" itemprop="image" />';
if ($hover_scenarios == 'fadebox') {
    $output .= '<div class="hover-overlay gradient"' . $hover_overlay . '></div>';
} else {
    if ($hover_scenarios == 'zoomout') {
        $output .= '<div class="image-hover-overlay" style="' . $item_bg_color . '"></div>';
    } else {
        $output .= '<div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>';
    }
}


if ($hover_scenarios == 'fadebox') {
    $output .= '<div class="grid-hover-icons">';



    if ($post_type == 'image' || $post_type == '') {
        $output .= '<a rel="portfolio-grid" title="' . get_the_title() . '" data-fancybox-group="portfolio-masonry-item" class="zoom-badge mk-lightbox" href="' . $image_src_array[0] . '"><i class="mk-jupiter-icon-plus-circle"></i></a>';
    } else if ($post_type == 'video') {
        $video_id   = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_single_video_id', true);
        $video_site = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_single_video_site', true);
        $video_url  = '';
        if ($video_site == 'vimeo') {
            $video_url = 'http' . ((is_ssl()) ? 's' : '') . '://vimeo.com/' . $video_id . '?autoplay=0';
        } elseif ($video_site == 'youtube') {
            $video_url = 'http' . ((is_ssl()) ? 's' : '') . '://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $video_id . '?autoplay=0';
        } elseif ($video_site == 'dailymotion') {
            $video_url = 'http' . ((is_ssl()) ? 's' : '') . '://www.dailymotion.com/video/' . $video_id . '?logo=0';
        }
        $output .= '<a title="' . get_the_title() . '" class="video-badge mk-lightbox" data-fancybox-group="portfolio-masonry-item" href="' . $video_url . '"><i class="mk-jupiter-icon-plus-circle"></i></a>';
    }

    $output .= '</div>';
}

if ($hover_scenarios == 'light-zoomin' ) {
    $output .= '<div class="grid-hover-icons">';



    if ($post_type == 'image' || $post_type == '') {
        $output .= '<a rel="portfolio-grid" title="' . get_the_title() . '" data-fancybox-group="portfolio-masonry-item" class="zoom-badge mk-lightbox" href="' . $image_src_array[0] . '"><i class="mk-jupiter-icon-plus-circle"></i></a>';
    } else if ($post_type == 'video') {
        $video_id   = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_single_video_id', true);
        $video_site = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_single_video_site', true);
        $video_url  = '';
        if ($video_site == 'vimeo') {
            $video_url = 'http' . ((is_ssl()) ? 's' : '') . '://vimeo.com/' . $video_id . '?autoplay=0';
        } elseif ($video_site == 'youtube') {
            $video_url = 'http' . ((is_ssl()) ? 's' : '') . '://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $video_id . '?autoplay=0';
        } elseif ($video_site == 'dailymotion') {
            $video_url = 'http' . ((is_ssl()) ? 's' : '') . '://www.dailymotion.com/video/' . $video_id . '?logo=0';
        }
        $output .= '<a title="' . get_the_title() . '" class="video-badge mk-lightbox" data-fancybox-group="portfolio-masonry-item" href="' . $video_url . '"><i class="mk-jupiter-icon-plus-circle"></i></a>';
    }

    $output .= '</div>';

}

if ($hover_scenarios != 'fadebox' && $hover_scenarios != 'light-zoomin' && $hover_scenarios != 'none') {
    $output .= '<div class="grid-hover-icons">';



    if ($post_type == 'image' || $post_type == '') {
        $output .= '<a data-fancybox-group="portfolio-grid" title="' . get_the_title() . '" class="zoom-badge mk-lightbox" href="' . $lightbox_full_size[0] . '"><i class="mk-jupiter-icon-plus-circle"></i></a>';
    } else if ($post_type == 'video') {
        $video_id   = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_single_video_id', true);
        $video_site = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_single_video_site', true);
        $video_url  = '';
        if ($video_site == 'vimeo') {
            $video_url = 'http' . ((is_ssl()) ? 's' : '') . '://vimeo.com/' . $video_id . '?autoplay=0';
        } elseif ($video_site == 'youtube') {
            $video_url = 'http' . ((is_ssl()) ? 's' : '') . '://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $video_id . '?autoplay=0';
        } elseif ($video_site == 'dailymotion') {
            $video_url = 'http' . ((is_ssl()) ? 's' : '') . '://www.dailymotion.com/video/' . $video_id . '?logo=0';
        }
        $output .= '<a title="' . get_the_title() . '" class="video-badge mk-lightbox" href="' . $video_url . '"><i class="mk-jupiter-icon-plus-circle"></i></a>';
    }

    $output .= '</div>';

}



if ($hover_scenarios != 'none') {

     $output .= ($hover_scenarios == 'slidebox') ? '<div class="portfolio-meta"' . $hover_overlay . '>' : '<div class="portfolio-meta">';
     $output .= '<h3 class="the-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h3><div class="clearboth"></div>';
     if ($meta_type == 'category') {
         $output .= '<div class="portfolio-categories">' . implode(', ', $terms_name) . ' </div>';
     } else {
         $output .= '<time class="portfolio-date" datetime="' . get_the_date() . '">' . get_the_date() . '</time>';
     }
     $output .= '</div><!-- Portfolio meta -->';

}

$output .= '</div><!-- Featured Image -->';


//$output .= ($hover_scenarios == 'fadebox' || $hover_scenarios == 'none') ? '</a><!-- project load -->' : '';
$output .= '</div>';


$output .= '</article>' . "\n\n\n";
return $output;}
```

I'm aware that what I need to modify in order to achieve my desired 2 column style is on and around line 30, particularly this part:

```
$column = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_masonry_img_size', true);
$column = !(empty($column)) ? $column : 'x_x';

switch ($column) {
    case 'x_x':
        $width  = 300;
        $height = 300;
        break;

    case 'two_x_x': // 
        $width  = 600;
        $height = 300;
        break;

    case 'three_x_x':
        $width  = 900;
        $height = 300;
        break;
    case 'four_x_x':
        $width  = 1200;
        $height = 300;
        break;

    case 'x_two_x':
        $width  = 300;
        $height = 600;
        break;
    case 'two_x_two_x':
        $width  = 600;
        $height = 600;
        break;
    case 'three_x_two_x':
        $width  = 900;
        $height = 600;
        break;

    case 'four_x_two_x':
        $width  = 1200;
        $height = 600;
        break;

    default:
        $width  = 300;
        $height = 300;
        break;
}
```

I have read several tutorials and attempted my best to create a 2 column function and use that in the switch instead but I fear that my knowledge of PHP is just not good enough to properly implement this.  Any thoughts, suggestions, or help would be greatly appreciated as I am no professional, we don't have the budget to hire one, and yet the responsibility has fallen on me as I'm the only somewhat web literate guy in the office.

Answer (score 1):

seeing as it is responsive it stands to reason that its the css that forces the 2 columns. I can't be certain because i cant see the code but i would do this with css media queries, making the items in the columns 100% width when reaching a specific screen width. if this is the case try and find the code that does that and make the width 50%.

I cannot guarantee this will work without seeing the whole code but its a start for you. the php doesn't know the screen width.